# If $f : X \to Z$ is a morphism of schemes, which factors through an open $i : U \to Z$ on the level of topological spaces...

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

If $f : X \to Z$ is a morphism of schemes, which factors through an open $i : U \to Z$ on the level of topological spaces... then is there a (unique) morphism of schemes $g : X \to U$ which makes the diagram commute.

I believe I just proved this (it is a tautology, just define the map to be the restriction of $f^{\#}$ on the relevant opens), but I want to make sure that I am not fooling myself (this stuff feels so complicated...).

Can someone comment?

Comment: Yes, that works. If you want to be very pedantic about it, you could check that this restriction is again a morphism of *locally* ringed spaces. (And you need to compare $g_* \mathcal O_X$ with $(f_* \mathcal O_X)|_U$.)

Comment: @Remy Thanks. But that is obvious because the induced maps on stalks only cares about some neighborhood basis, right?

Comment: Right, that's the idea. Also, there's a little work involved in comparing $g_* \mathcal O_X$ to $(f_* \mathcal O_X)|_U$. (I edited this into my previous post, but by then you had already responded. I'm not allowed to change it back, but I will say it again.)

Comment: @Remy I want to write something like $i_* ((f_* O_X) | U) = i_* i^{-1} (f_* O_X) = f_* O_X = (ig)_* O_X = i_* g_* O_X$, then I would like to cancel the $i_*$ because it is a monomorphism. Does that make sense? I think I may have done the same check when I wrote out the big diagram for my original claim, but honestly I am getting pretty confused. If you know how to prove this very cleanly I would appreciate it if you could show me.

Comment: No, $i_* i^{-1} \mathcal F$ is not equal to $\mathcal F$ in general. In fact, you can describe explicitly what $i_* i^{-1}$ does to a sheaf $\mathcal F$. For this problem, just work on $U$ in stead of trying to work on $Z$.

Comment: @Remy But in this case $F(V) = F(U \cap V)$ (because the map $f$ factors through the inclusion $U$), so doesn't $i_* i^{-1} F = F$ here? Maybe I am making a mistake, but I have convinced myself that $i_* i^{-1} F(V) = i^{-1} F(i^{-1}(V)) = i^{-1} F(U \cap V) = F(U \cap V)$.

Comment: Oh, you're right, in this case it does work, and your argument might even be correct. However, it seems neater to prove it directly on $U$.

Comment: @Remy I am not sure what you mean by proving it on $U$. Do you think you could elaborate (maybe in an answer below)? I would really like to make my thought process about these kinds of details cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \colon X \to U$ denote the topological map.

> **Lemma 1.** We have a canonical isomorphism $f_* \mathcal O_X|_U \cong g_* \mathcal O_X$.

*Proof.* Let $V \subseteq U$ be open. Then $f^{-1}(V) = g^{-1}(V)$, so
$$(f_* \mathcal O_X|_U)(V) = f_* \mathcal O_X (V) = \mathcal O_X (f^{-1} V) = \mathcal O_X(g^{-1}V) = (g_* \mathcal O_X)(V).$$

> **Lemma 2.** The restriction of $f^\# \colon \mathcal O_Z \to f_* \mathcal O_X$ to $U$ gives a morphism of sheaves of rings
>   $$g^\# \colon \mathcal O_U \to g_* \mathcal O_X.$$

*Proof.* The identification of Lemma 1 is an isomorphism of sheaves of rings.

> **Lemma 3.** Let $z \in U$. Then $\mathcal O_{Z,z} = \mathcal O_{U, z}$.

*Proof.* One is the colimit over all opens $V \subseteq Z$ containing $z$, and the other over all $V \subseteq U$ containing $z$. The latter forms a cofinal system in the former, thus the colimits agree.

> **Proposition.** The pair $(g,g^\#)$ is a morphism of locally ringed spaces.

*Proof.* Lemma 1 and Lemma 2 show that it is a morphism of ringed spaces. Let $x \in X$. By assumption, the map $f^\#_x \colon \mathcal O_{Z, f(x)} \to \mathcal O_{X,x}$ is a local ring homormophism, hence by Lemma 3 so is $g^\#_x \colon \mathcal O_{U,f(x)} \to \mathcal O_{X,x}$.

**Remark.** One then needs to go on to prove that $f$ factors through $g$, and that such a factorisation is unique. I will not carry out these steps.

Comment: Thanks. This is certainly cleaner than what I had written out - I did not think to apply the restriction functor $|_U$ as a way to push the problem over to $U$. I think it is clear how to prove the rest - just apply the functor $i_*$, and observe $i_* i^{-1} (f^{\sharp}) = i_*(g^{\#}) \circ i^{\#}$  as $i^{\#}$ is restriction to $U$ as a map $O_Z \to i_* (O_U))$. And also $i_* i^{-1} f^{\#} = f^{\#}$ because $f_* O_X(V) = f_*O_X(W \cap V)$, so we can commute the restriction to after $f^{\#}$, where it acts as the identity. Thanks again for taking the time to answer such a basic question!